# нужна ли запятая во фразе "бессмысленная глупая смерть"?

Tags: запятые

подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в месте, что выделено курсивом между словами "бессмысленную" и "глупую" в следующем предложении.

пойдя на этот принцип, ты обрёк себя на ***бессмысленную глупую смерть***

Comment: Вы находитесь там, где предпочитают писать правильно, особо не экспериментируют и ждут от других немногого — хотя бы соблюдения базовых правил на письме.

Answer (score 1):

*Пойдя на этот принцип, ты обрёк себя на **бессмысленную,  глупую** смерть.*

Запятая ставится между однородными определениями, которые в данном тексте сближены по значению, то есть обозначают одно и то же качество.